# Subtract seconds from Timestamp In GCP Spanner (PostgreSQL dialect)

Tags: google-cloud-spanner

I have a Java Spring Boot app working with GCP Spanner. One of the tasks the app should do is cleaning up a table based on rows' timestamp in Spanner from time to time. It should perform the following sql query:

```
DELETE FROM {table_name} WHERE CreatedAt <= TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)
```

It works fine with Spanner SQL Dialect, but doesn't work with PostgreSQL.
The errors I receive state that there are no these functions:TIMESTAMP_SUB() and CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(). It also doesn't support INTERVAL.

I went through [Spanner docs](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/reference/postgresql/functions-and-operators#date-time-operators) and got an impression that Spanner supports very limited number of PosgreSQL functions.
And in case of date/time operators only subtraction of days is supported, which doesn't work for my case obviously.

Do I miss something regarding date/time operators?
Is there a workaround for subtracting seconds/minutes from timestamps in GCP Spanner with Postgresql Dialect?